# "end up" peculiar properties

Tags: clauses, complements, predicative-complements

Just putting together a lexical lesson on making life changes and thought I'd use a sentence with 'end up'. However, when I ran through various sample sentences I noticed that it is quite an unusual beast in that it licenses verb+ing phrases, adjective phrases and prepositional phrases and noun phrases.

So:

> 1. I ended up *drunk and broke.* (AdjP)
> 2. That's how I ended up *here.* (PP)
> 3. I ended up *without a penny to my name.* (PP)
> 4. I ended up *running the company.*  (V+ing)
> 5. He ended up *a hero.* (NP)

Thus it would seem to form complex transitive clauses, the complements describing the state of the 'subject' (or predicand). Kind of meaning 'at the end of the story [the subject] was'.

Yet because it ends with 'up' (a preposition) - you'd expect it just to licence verb+ing or a noun phrase.

So what is it exactly - any ideas?

Comment: I fell and landed ass end up.

Comment: I like it. One I hadn't thought of! I ended up landing ass end up.

Comment: I'm not sure it's *that* "unusual". ***To be***, which is probably the most common verb in English, can also be used in all these contexts. So can ***to start, to begin***, I think.

Comment: Few would call the _up_ in _end up_ a preposition nowadays. Theres a vast difference between _I ended up here_ and _I worked up here_. Only in the second is 'up here ' an adverbial.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I climbed the ladder and I ended up here.

Comment: I lost my balance, started rolling, and ended up down at the bottom of the hill.

Comment: @Hot Licks - You may also have climbed the ladder and ended up up here. There's a vast difference between MWV-using  _I ended up here_ and _I worked up here_. Particle / preposition.

Comment: +1. :) -- Perhaps your examples might not actually be transitive clauses. Also, maybe it could be possible that your #1 and #5 examples might be thought to involve predicative complements (and/or oblique PCs), maybe; consider: *"I [ended up/became] drunk and broke"*, and *"He [ended up/became] a hero"*

Comment: I would probably consider your #2 *"That's how I ended up here. (PP)"* as involving a locative complement ("here"), not a PC: consider "That's how I ended up in New York City."

Comment: 2002 *CGEL*, page 286-8, "6.3.2 Constructions containing verb + intransitive preposition idioms", discusses this a little bit; on page 288, section "Structure vi: verb - prep - (as) PC, as in *end up [(as) captain]*", [51], it provides in the text the example *"She ended up [ broken-hearted / captain / as captain ]."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the phrases following *up* here are commonly found as predicative complements. Here are some more examples of such predicative complements:

- Don't get her angry (AdjP)
- Get her here as soon as possible (PP)
- Get her into the taxi. (PP)
- I got her running errands for me. (V+ing)
- I am a nutter (NP - I don't think this sense of *GET* allows NP's as predicative complement so I've had to use the verb *BE* instead).

The predicative complements here are complements of *get*. In the Original Poster's examples, the preposition *up* is a complement of the verb *END*. However, the Original Poster's predicative complements are not complements of the preposition *up*, they are complements of verb *END*. In other words the verb *end* is taking two complements here.

(Assuming that *here* is a preposition in the OP's examples) *END* is a verb and *up* is a preposition functioning as a complement of that verb. The predicative complements the OP describes are also complements of the verb, not the preposition.

Answer (score 2):

1. I am partial to the analysis in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, which treats *up* here as an *intransitive preposition*, analogous to an *intransitive verb* in that it does not take an object.

   > The traditional account does not allow for a preposition without a complement, but within a framework where prepositions function as heads of phrases, like verbs, nouns, adjectives, and adverbs, there is again no principled basis for imposing such a condition. Compare:

   ```
     [7]    WITH COMPLEMENT                         WITHOUT COMPLEMENT
         i a. She was eating an apple.              b. She was eating.
        ii a. She's the director of the company.    b. She's the director.  
       iii a. I'm certain it's genuine.             b. I'm certain.  
        iv a. I haven't seen her since the war.     b. I haven't seen her since.
   ```

   > The presence or absence of a complement has no bearing on the classification of the head in[i-iii], where in both the [a] and [b] members of the pair *eating* is a verb, *director* a a noun, and *certain* an adjective. There is no reason to treat [iv] any differently, and we accordingly take *since* as a preposition not only in [a], but also in [b], where traditional grammar analyses it as an adverb.
   >     We also include in the preposition category certain words like *downstairs*, which never take complements. (600-601)
2. I further suggest that in the vast majority of so-called 'particle verbs' the bare preposition is a preposition phrase with (at least in origin) a locative sense, and that in that role it acts as Predicate Complement imputing a literal or figurative location to the subject. In the particular case of *end up*, this "location" is not spatial but telic: this is [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdictio101murruoft#page/410/mode/2up)’s sense **18.b** of **Up**, *adv.*<sup>1</sup>

   > **18.** To or toward a state of completion or finality. (Frequently serving merely to emphasize the import of the verb.)
   >   […]
   >     **b.** With other verbs, denoting progress to or towards an end.
   >     **1307** *York Memo. Bk.* (Suretees) I. 181. Oute taken girdels that er fully wroght up.  *c* **1400** *Laud Troy Bk.* 14614 They..heled hum up with medycyns. […] **1869** *Pall Mall G.* 19 Aug. 5/1 Prices have subsequently firmed up in many instances.

Under this analysis, there is no need to seek a direct dependency or other syntactic relationship between *up* and the many sorts of Predicate Complement which follow it: the idiom merely calls for two different PCs, one characterizing the predication as telic and the other characterizing the particular telos attained.