# to switch up, to change up – why are these now taking the preposition "up"?

Tags: verbs, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Does anyone know the root of the emergence of usage of the preposition "up" with the verbs "to switch" and "to change"?

Comment: See [this Answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/237904/24489), where use of *up* in the sense "To or toward a state of completion or finality. (Frequently serving merely to emphasize the import of the verb.)" is traced by *OED 1* to the early 14th century.

Comment: Certainly "change up" has been a part of American baseball jargon for over 50 years.

Comment: Thanks. It has only spread to British and Irish English usage in the past few years. I noticed three of my acquaintances use the construction in the past year.

Comment: Example sentence with and without the usage would be helpful.

Comment: @TonyWilson I've been driving cars since 1966, I've been changing the gears up (and down) all that time and my parents were changing up and down while driving all the time I was growing up. I believe this usage is at least as old as motor vehicles and is the source of the phrase for other uses.

Comment: -1 for lack of details. At the very least,  provide sample sentences that illustrate the phenomenon you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

*Mix up* springs to mind as a good example of this type of *up*.  The semantic difference between *mix* and *mix up* goes some way to demonstrate the meaning of *up* in the two phrases you've highlighted.  Something that has been mixed up is by definition, quite thoroughly mixed.

Rather than framing this in terms of "completion or finality" as the OED does however, I would venture to frame it in terms of "significant or notable change from a previous state".  While these definitions largely overlap, I think there is a hair between them. One refers to the future and another to the past. Rather than imply reaching an endpoint, it points towards a "step change" of events; the effect is to leave the situation qualitatively different from what it was previously.  The up indicates a marked, notable difference.

If I "mess up" someone's hair, I'm not saying "I mess their hair to or towards a situation where the messing is complete", but more "I mess their hair to a point at which their hair is now categorically more messy than it was before".

The same with change up and switch up, they carry a connotation of a "certain level" (which I'll admit is ambiguous) of change being created.  When you say "change up", the up indicates, "changing to the extent that the state of affairs is notably different from what it was previously".  The same with switch up, which to me seems to imply an order of magnitude of "switching" that "switch" doesn't necessarily have on its own.

Although in the case of switch and change, often the addition of up doesn't change much in the meaning (if I change a routine, or change up the routine, is there a substantial meaning difference?), it would make sense that in cases where either are appropriate, that the "up" form is becoming more fashionable.  While not all that different in the explicit meaning, the *up* gives a connotation of a "freshness" or "break from the past" in a way merely changing something or switching something doesn't.

When I tell you I'm going to "change up" the routine I'm really signalling that the new routine will be in some sense a breath of fresh air, maybe even that this change will *shake things up*.

Comment: This could be condensed to a much more concise form I know, I'll have a look at refining it tonight.  Hopefully it addresses the substance of the issue though.